# React native touch multi selection

Tags: react-native, touch-event

I'm trying to achieve next functionality: when user touched a screen with a finger and moving it - all underlying buttons that user goes through are selected (if it is possible - keep track of all the button names)

This is a sample code for buttons 
What I tried to do:
1. Track onTouchStart, onTouchMove and onTouchEnd events of the parent view;
I was able to get node target id but I can't exchange it into a button component
2. Set onTouchStart and onTouchEnd events for each of the buttons;
If I go from button 1 to button 2 - I can't trigger or propagate touch event of the second button

Any help would be appreciated

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Button} from 'react-native';

class SampleTable extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View
                    style={[{ width: "90%", margin: 10, backgroundColor: "gray" }]}>
                    <Button
                        title="Button One"
                        color="gray"
                    />
                </View>
                <View
                    style={[{ width: "90%", margin: 10, backgroundColor: "gray" }]}>
                    <Button
                        title="Button Two"
                        color="gray"
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default SampleTable
```